# Uncommon type of logical tree

Tags: logic

I'm trying to reproduce such tree:

[image]

I know that it was created with Latex, but since I'm a beginner, I really don't know where to start. Would it be possible to create something like that in TkiZ?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: What type of tree is that? (I've not seen one like that before.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know its name. It is mainly used for checking if formula is tautology.

Comment: Oh, I see how it works. Weird. (That is, different and so looks-weird-to-me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can produce this kind of diagram using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); below, an option using a `matrix of math nodes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand\mynot{\mathord{\sim}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={
    text width=5em,
    inner xsep=7pt,
    text depth=0.75ex,
    text height=2ex
  },
  nodes in empty cells,
  column 1/.style={align=left},
  column 2/.style={align=right},
  column 3/.style={align=left},
  column 4/.style={align=right},
] (mat)
{
& 1 & 0 & \\
& \alpha\to\beta & & \\
& \mynot\beta\to\mynot\gamma & & \\
& \gamma & & \\
& & \alpha & \\
& |[align=left]|\mynot\beta & |[align=right]|\mynot\gamma & C1 \\
& \text{NO} & & N1  \\
\alpha & \beta & & C1 \\
};

% some additional labels
\node[label={right:$\gamma$},anchor=south,yshift=3pt] at (mat-7-3.south east) {};
\node[label={below:$X$},anchor=north,yshift=8pt] at (mat-7-3.south east) {};
\node[label={left:$\beta$},anchor=south,yshift=3pt] at (mat-7-1.south east) {};

% tiny lines at the bottom
\foreach \Colu in {1,3}
{
\draw 
  ([xshift=-4pt]mat-8-\Colu.south west) --
  ([xshift=4pt]mat-8-\Colu.south west)
;
\draw 
  ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=-2pt]mat-8-\Colu.south west) --
  ([xshift=4pt,yshift=-2pt]mat-8-\Colu.south west)
;
}

% thick lines inside the matrix
\begin{scope}[ultra thick]
\draw
  (mat-2-2.north west) --
  (mat-2-3.north east)
;
\draw 
  (mat-1-2.north east) --
  (mat-6-2.north east) --
  (mat-6-1.north east) --
  (mat-7-1.south east) --
  (mat-7-1.south west) --
  (mat-8-1.south west)
  ;
\draw 
  (mat-7-1.south east) --
  (mat-7-3.south west) --
  (mat-8-3.south west)
  ;
\draw 
  (mat-6-2.north east) --
  (mat-6-3.north east) --
  (mat-7-3.south east)
  ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]